# Writing data to CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write the output of a win32_process output to csv

```
def get_Process():
    #for process in c.win32_Process():
    for process in c.win32_Process (name="notepad.exe"):
        with open('D:\writeData.csv', mode='w') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        #print(process.ProcessId,process.Name)
            writer.writerow(['Process Name','Process ID'])
            writer.writerow(['process.Name','process.processId'])
```

When i am executing the code, it is not giving me any error but it is not creating the csv file so not able to write also.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here

Comment: most certainly, the `writerow` statements have to be inside the `with` context manager.

Comment: tried..no luck..updated the answer also.

Comment: everything inside the context manager produces the wanted output in my case. There is another typo: Extra whitespace in front of the opening brace behind `Process`.

Comment: Even i tried creating only the csv by commenting the writerow lines, but even csv not getting  created

Comment: If you run only the part in the context manager, do you get an error? Do you have the drive `D:` ?

Comment: yes i do have the drive..and as i told even if i run the with context only without writerow it is not creating any csv file.

Comment: in a new python file, paste only the for rows starting with `with` and in the first line put `import csv`. What happens, when you run that file?

Comment: i ran the below code
```
import wmi
import csv
with open('D:\writeData.csv', mode='w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        #print(process.ProcessId,process.Name)
    writer.writerow(['Process Name','Process ID'])
```
It created the csv and written the header

Comment: So, the error is not in the piece of code you showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_Process():
    #for process in c.win32_Process():
    for process in c.win32_Process(name="notepad.exe"):
        with open('D:\writeData.csv', mode='w') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        #print(process.ProcessId,process.Name)
            writer.writerow(['Process Name','Process ID'])
            writer.writerow([process.Name,process.processId])
```

Should do what you want. Note that I changed the second write from strings to actual objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
csvData = [['Person','Age'],['Peter','22'],['Jasmine', '21'],['Sam', '24']]

with open('person.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerows(csvData)
csvFile.close
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.